# Single instance of ServletContextListener in cluster

Tags: java, performance, servlets, singleton

Is it possible to make only one instance of ServletContextListener across multiple nodes in a clustered application server? Have a requirement to start a logic at application startup and repeat same every 5 minute till application is destroyed, but it should be done by only one thread even in clustered environment. Tried writing singleton class , ServletContextListener ,@Singleton annotation but everything fails in clustered environment by initiating number of instances equal to number of nodes.

Any ideas to resolve this will really help me proceed. Spring or any other framework is not allowed, has to be in pure java API.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a distributed lock or a leader election mechanism in order to enforce a single execution in the cluster.

It's not an easy task without using a external library or third party application (for leader election or lock management)

If you're using a database, you can use it to implement mutual exclusion and to check if the task has already been executed : with a custom table and optimistic or pessimistic locking (*select for update*)

Comment: Thank you, I thought of using database table approach only , but wanted to verify once whether any better approach available than this.

Comment: I came across weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService (as I am using weblogic), but finding it hard to make it work. Created a jar which has simple class implementing this interface and some logic in activate() and deactivate() method and modified META-INF/application.xml to register this jar as java module, also modified META-INF/weblogic-application.xml to register my class as singleton class. But when I try to deploy getting "MyClass has been registered as a singleton already." Anyone knows any other configuration I am missing?